Showing non existence of continous function which "jumps" between two circles
I am thinking of how to make the fact the idea in this post for proving that fundamental group of a disjoint union of circle is again $\mathbb{Z}$. I am trying to figure out why it is that we can't have a curve which jumps from one circle to another.
Well, I think maybe it has something to do with connectedness but no one said that the segments of curve lying on each circle need be open... so, I am a bit confused.
Hints?

The continuous image of a connected set is connected. This is a standard lemma/exercise in topology.

I can prove that. It's an easy proof by contradiction, but I sort of find difficult the application here exactly @CheerfulParsnip

One more lemma/exercise: a connected subspace of a larger space must lie in a connected component.

The definition of a curve is a continuous map from either an interval or a circle, depending on the approach, but either way it's from a connected set. If its continuous image includes both circles, and each circle is open and disjoint from the other...

Ah okay now it makes sense. I never dealt with connected. Components @CheerfulParsnop

Consider a a space $X$ and a basepoint $x_0 \in X$. Let $P$ be the path component of $x_0$ in $X$. Each loop $u : [0,1] \to X$ based at $x_0$ has a path connected image containing $x_0$, thus the image  must be contained in $P$. Similarly homotopies between loops based at $x_0$ must have images in $P$. This shows that
$$\pi_1(X,x_0) = \pi_1(P,x_0) .$$
The disjoint union $X$ of circles is not connected because each of the circles is open in the disjoint union. In particular $X$ is not path connected. Given $x_0 \in X$, the path component of $x_0$ is one the circles $C_i$. Therefore $\pi_1(X,x_0) = \pi_1(C_i,x_0) \approx \mathbb Z$.
